# A class contains $5$ boys and $5$ girls.What is the probability that some two girls will sit next to one another?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A class contains $5$ boys and $5$ girls.For the class banquet,they select seats at random around a circular table that seats $10$. What is the probability that some two girls will sit next to one another ?

I've reasoned as follows about the problem:

Let $A$ be the even that some two girls sit next to each other.

Then $P(A)=1-P(\lnot A) $

So the problem now breaks down to find all the combinations in which no two girls sit next to one another.

For that I have considered to let the $5$ girls sit around the table ,without the boys.

I can have $4!$ distinct combinations,and the same goes if I would let the $5$ boys sit around the table without the girls.

Now my intuition here was that whatever combination I have of the $5$ girls around the table,I can always "overlap" the combinations of the $5$ boys in between each girl .

So that I have $4!\cdot 4!$ combinations in which no girl sit next to another girl,which yields a probability $P(\lnot A)=\cfrac{4!4!}{9!}$

Finally I have that $P(A)=1-P(\lnot A)=1-\cfrac{4!4!}{9!}\approx 99 \% $

This last result really leaves me a bit skeptical,I belive I have done some mistake conceptually...

Comment: 100%! Boys are annoying!!!

Comment: I think your numerator for the complement should be $5!4!$ since any arrangement of boys can be rotated (in 5 different ways) before being interwoven with the girls.  Other than that I think your reasoning is ok.

Comment: @paw88789 Shouldn't I have that the boys can be arranged in  $(5-1)!$ factorial ways ?

Comment: @Mr.Y No.  Once the girls are placed, we can line up the boys in $5!$ ways relative to a particular girl.  Start on her immediate right.  We have five choices for the first boy.  Move to the next remaining open seat on her right.  We have four choices for the boy who sits there.  Continue to move around the circle in a counterclockwise direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that one of the girls is Abigail.  Seat her first.  As we move counterclockwise around the table starting with the seat to her immediate right, we can seat the remaining $9$ people in $9!$ ways.

If no two girls sit next to each other, then the boys and girls must sit in alternating seats, so there are four seats available to the remaining girls once Abigail has taken her seat.  We can arrange the other four girls in those seats in $4!$ ways as we move counterclockwise around the table from Abigail.  This leaves five seats for the boys.  Relative to Abigail, they can be arranged in these seats in $5!$ ways as we move counterclockwise around the circle from the seat to her immediate right.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which no two girls sit together is $4!5!$.

Hence, the probability that two of the girls sit together is 
$$1 - \frac{4!5!}{9!}$$

Comment: Yep, I'm glad to see that our answers agree with each other (resulting in $\frac{125}{126}$)...

Answer (score 3):

Forget the circle for a minute.

The total number of permutations is $10!=3628800$.

The number of permutations with no two girls sitting next to each other is $5!\cdot5!\cdot2=28800$.

Hence the probability of two girls sitting next to each other is $1-\frac{28800}{3628800}\approx99.2\%$.

Comment: This agrees with my answer,that was completely unexpected.Thank you for the check up.

Comment: @Mr.Y: No it doesn't. $1-\cfrac{4!4!}{9!}\approx99.84\%$.

Comment: yes but you say to forget about the circle,but here this is clearly not doable as configurations change.

Comment: @Mr.Y: That's why I edited my answer and added "for a minute"... After that, you can "take the line and connect its ends in order to create the circle". I hope you understand my "graphical" description here. If not, then please let me know.

Comment: Okay .But I am left with one last doubt,if you permute the boys and girls in $10!$ ways and then connect the line endpoints to form a circle,some arrangements are to be considered the same.Why here this argument works ?

Comment: I will borrow Abigail from N.F. Taussig.  Once she is seated, there are $\binom{9}{4}$ equally likely ways  to choose the seats for the girls. Only one of these has no girls sitting next to each other.  So the probability no two are next to each other is $\dfrac{1}{\binom{9}{4}}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  That is the simplest solution.  I have learned a lot from reading your posts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few correct answers, but I think there is a significantly easier way to do this. First, we don't need to distinguish between different girls or different boys, so instead let's approach the problem in terms of $5$ red balls and $5$ blue balls. Second, a circular table can be thought of as a rectangular table, we just have to be careful about the two end seats.

Now, the question is how many ways can we line up $5$ red balls and $5$ blue balls such that no two red balls are next to eachother or on opposite ends of the line. Choosing to place a ball in position 1 forces everything else, so there are only $2$ ways(either red first or blue first). How many ways all together are there to line up the balls? $\binom{10}5$ giving us $$P=1-\frac{2}{\binom{10}5}\approx 99.2\%$$

Comment: Nice observation.

Comment: Thanks. If there is one thing I have learned about probability theory, it is that half the battle is finding the right sample space to work in.